# Wpml Different Language per domain

Tags: wordpress, wpml

Is this possible to  have multi language website by wpml that each language has specific domain without clone website to a new folder? I am using Language per parameter so it doesn't need to have different folders and use lots of storage resources , is this possible to use different domain and dont use extra storage?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as per their documentation:

> ...For example, if you have a German translation of your English
> website, you can set it to have a different domain:
>
> example.com → English
>
> example.de → German

https://wpml.org/documentation/getting-started-guide/language-setup/language-url-options/how-to-use-wpml-with-different-domains-per-language/

Note: on top of modifying the WPML settings in the wp-admin dashboard, you will also need to configure the DNS settings correctly for both domains - that's on the side of the domain registrar.